# JavaScript count 1, 2, 3 and redirect

Tags: javascript

I want to count on my site from 3 to 1 (3, 2, 1, <redirect>), like on sh.st or adf.ly. I'm really new to JavaScript, can anyone help me?

Comment: `setTimeout()` plus `.innerHTML = ...` plus `document.location.href = ...`

Comment: There are many questions about creating a countdown, I'm sure you can find them if you google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way to creat a countdown

```
//Calls countdown function
var count = 3;
countdown(count);

//counts and redirect
function countdown(timer) {
    //Keeps the interval ID for later clear
    var intervalID;
    intervalID = setInterval(function () {

        display(timer);
        timer = timer - 1;

        if (timer < 0) {
            //Clears the timeout 
            clearTimeout(intervalID);
            // You can redirect the user after it 
            // window.location.assign("YourURL");
        }
    }, 1000);


}

//Modifies the countdown display
function display(timer) {
    //Execute your diplay modification logic
}
```

You can check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y0np5n5t/2/)